# Pass variable from plugin back to cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

The [Cordova plugin](https://github.com/jleszczynski/cordova-vr-player) I'm using plays a VR video file, and is called via `GoogleVRPlayer.playVideo(videoUrl, fallbackVideoUrl)`.

Somewhere in the .java files of the plugin, there's:

```
@Override
public void onLoadError(String errorMessage) {
  // I want to know if this function is executed
  Log.e(TAG, "Error loading video: " + errorMessage);
}
```

Basically, when the video fails to load, I want to set a variable in my javascript in cordova to "error", for example `var video_status = "error"`, so I can use this information later on in my app.

I've found some answers that would possibly solve my problem, but I can't seem to integrate it the right way. I have very little experience with native plugins and Java.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Cordova plugin `GoogleVRPlayer` launches a new Activity (`VrVideoActivity`), I would use a Singleton class as an interstitial data bridge between the two Activites to hold the error message.
This is because, on launching the video player activity, your app (the Cordova activity) is paused in the background and will only resume execution once the video player activity is closed.
By using the intermediate class, both the Cordova plugin and the video activity are able to share data.

So I would do something like this:

Create a new file called `CordovaBridge.java` in `cordova-vr-player/src/android/java/neotrino/`

```
package com.neotrino;

public class CordovaBridge {
  private String errorMsg = null;
  public String getErrorMsg() {return errorMsg;}
  public void setErrorMsg(String errorMsg) {this.errorMsg = errorMsg;}

  private static final CordovaBridge holder = new CordovaBridge();
  public static CordovaBridge getInstance() {return holder;}
}
```

Modify `GoogleVRPlayer.java` as follows:

```
import com.neotrino.CordovaBridge;

@Override
public void onResume(boolean multitasking) {
    cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String errorMsg = CordovaBridge.getInstance().getErrorMsg();
            if(errorMsg != null){
              webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.video_status = '"+errorMsg+"'");
            }
        }
  });
}
```

Modify `VrVideoActivity.java` as follows:

```
import com.neotrino.CordovaBridge;

@Override
public void onLoadError(String errorMessage) {
  // I want to know if this function is executed
  Log.e(TAG, "Error loading video: " + errorMessage);
  CordovaBridge.getInstance().setErrorMsg(errorMessage);
}
```

I haven't tested the above code, but in terms of an approach it should give you an approximation on which to base your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get these errors when trying to build the project: `error: cannot find symbol
                      webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.video_status = 'error'"); symbol: variable webView` and `error: cannot find symbol
               cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          symbol:   variable cordova`

Comment: My original solution assumed that the plugin executed within the Cordova activity - having looked at the source code for the plugin, it actually uses a separate activity which complicates how you would communicate the error message back to your Cordova app. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your edit! I'm getting a build error now: `cannot find symbol import com.neotrino.CordovaBridge;
                           ^
          symbol:   class CordovaBridge` for both .java files...

Comment: You will need to inject CordovaBridge.java as a source file in plugin.xml. Note that this is not a trivial edit of the plugin.

Comment: I understand. Probably why I'm having such a hard time figuring this out. New build error after injecting the source file in plugin.xml: `error: cannot find symbol
            CordovaInterface cordova = CordovaBridge.getInstance().setErrorMsg(errorMessage);
            ^
          symbol:   class CordovaInterface
          location: class VrVideoActivity.ActivityEventListener`

Comment: I've imported `org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterface;` in VrVideoActivity.java, and run into this error: `error: incompatible types: void cannot be converted to CordovaInterface`. I have a feeling I'm getting closer...

Comment: Update: after removing `CordovaInterface cordova = `, the project builds successfully. When the script hits the decoding-error, it's not populating the `video_status` variable. It just shows me a blank screen with the error message. The console log says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined"

Comment: I assume this latter error is in the JS layer: are you waiting for the `deviceready` event to fire in your app before attempting to invoke the plugin?

Comment: Yes, I am. I've changed `cordova` to `this.cordova` which removes the error. Everything is error free, but how can I access `video_status`? If I just do `console.log(video_status)`, the console says: "undefined"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146436/discussion-between-davealden-and-binoculars).

Comment: was this ever resolved? I am trying to send data from a java plugin to cordova